# Ruby on Rails 2.3 populating and validating non-AR models from form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a ActiveRecord model which contains a serialized field which consists of an Array of a custom non ActiveRecord model (a simple class, with a couple of attributes).

I'm trying to figure out a way to integrate population and validation for each of the serialized items together with the parent model but can't find a elegant way for doing so.

The serialized model "initialize" method receives an "attributes" hash, and simply populates the class attributes with those. This is just fine, beside the fact that when receiving the data from a form, the data is received as a string data rather than an actual type.
ActiveRecord model knows how to deal with this, and does typecasting based on the Schema before 
the model instance is saved to the db. Is there anything I can do (beside typecasting right in the "initialize" method) to make the behavior similar to the AR models?

Also, I'm trying to use the "Validatable" gem for validating my NON AR-Model, but seems like there are validations which cannot be defined there like, when using "validates_numericality_of" and defining that the number is bigger than 0.

There is the "if" parameter which can be passed to to it, but it occurs before the numericality checking and then when executing:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :if => lambda { self.price >= 0.0 }, :message => "Price must be greater or equal to 0"
```

If I entered a string inside the "price" field, when I try to check if the model is valid, I get an exception thrown since "price" is a string and i'm trying to compare it to a number...

hope it's ok I've asked two questions in one thread... but they're kind of related.

Thanks

Comment: I hope you have solved it by now, but you would need to capture the model instance in a variable, as the code is evaluated in class' context rather than instance's context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `self.price.to_i`?